# How do you add a new column to an existing datawindow in Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have inherited an old project that was written in PowerBuilder 11.2.  I need to add a column to a datawindow, then add the control to the window?  I have gone into Design->data source and made the change in the source there, and I have also made the change in edit source=>retrieve statement as well (just to be sure).  The form loads fine, I just cannot find out how to add a new column in the design and data windows. I am looking for any help on this at all.

Thanks.

Comment: You should only need to change it one place, in Design>Data Source. Successfully editing DataWindow source requires a thorough understanding of the DataWindow. PowerBuilder expects the DW syntax to be perfect. You'll get no diagnostics, it simply won't work. If you've edited the source, I recommend you start over with a clean copy.

Answer (score 1):

While the Design pane of the DataWindow painter is current, there is a dropdown toolbar button (4th one after Save) or you can use the Insert menu. Then click on the design pane where you want the control to land.

Comment: If your new column is editable and you want the value to be saved to the database, make sure you change the 'Update Properties' of the datawindow object to include it.  (In datawindow painter choose menu option 'Rows' then 'Update Properties'.

Comment: I can do this, but I cannot see the new column from my updated SQL Statement.  Is there a way to "refresh" this to get the column to show up as a selection?

Comment: @john You have to manually add it to the data definition by right clicking and appending a row.

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming you have entered the data source area where you have changed the SQL.  Make sure when you go back to defining the layout you do so by selecting the "return" icon (or file\return).  If you have added the column it shoudl immediately show up in the Column Specification List (look in view menu if that isn't showing and toggle it on.

All of the data columns selected will be listed there; however, if more than a single table is selected from PB will often name the column "tablename_columnname", so look for that.  As mentioned before, once the column is there you can either drag and drop it where you want it from the ColumnSpec list (using the very left edge) or through the menu as mentioned above.

GL
G2-